# Intel HD graphics 3000 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, intel-graphics

I just installed Ubuntu 18 and I am not really sure that my graphics board is used at maximum capacity. Does Ubuntu 18 has the latest driver built in? I am planing to connect my laptop (thinkpad X220) to a HD TV and I want to have the best image quality possible.
This is what I could find in Terminal:

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:26 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I noticed that the same driver was used also in Ubuntu 13. Is there no newer version?

Update: I want to use Boinc on my laptop in the future and there are projects that use the GPU for computation. I want to be sure everything is going to be OK. (Now I have a little bit of time to play around with Ubuntu but in the future I will be very busy. That's why I want to set up everything now so that I do not have any problems down the road).
Thanks for the answer:).

Comment: Where do you see any driver version? You don't need to install anything.

Comment: The driver is roughly the latest version, yes. Intel drivers are developed in the upstream kernel and xorg trees. There's nothing extra you need to install. If you think you are having some particular issue, and you'd like help with that, it would be best to [edit] your question and describe what exactly is wrong.

Comment: why don't you just try ? Intel graphics usually work out of the box.